# Finding the value/text of an A tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Something's not quite right here.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("a#edit").click(function() {
                $("div#search").addClass("hidden");
                $("div#edit").removeClass("hidden");
            alert((this).val());
            return false;
            }); 
        } 
);
```

And later:

```
<a href="#" id="edit">10.1001</a>
```

I want to get the value "10.1001" from this.  `alert((this).val());` doesn't seem to work, nor does `alert((this).text());`.  Can someone point out really quickly what I'm missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `(this).val()` you want `$(this).text()` for anchors.

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is for input type elements, [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is used to get the text within a tag :)

Your code should look like this overall, note the addd `$` before `(this)`:

```
$(function() {
  $("a#edit").click(function() {
    $("div#search").addClass("hidden");
    $("div#edit").removeClass("hidden");
    alert($(this).val());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: **12 seconds**..? Man; it's like competing with a ninja, sometimes... =)

Comment: @ricebowl - Remember that we see the questions at different times...an answer may not be as quick as it seems :) SO runs on multiple servers, each caches that listing page for a few min, the cache on the server your IP goes to may refresh before another, or after...so different people see different questions quickly, depending on which it was posted vs when their server's cache refreshed :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be forgetting the crucial `$` symbol (an alias for `jQuery`), which when followed by parenthesis (`(...)`), calls the jQuery constructor and provides all of its methods.

Try:

```
alert( $(this).text() );
```

The keyword `this` actually provides a reference to the DOM element being clicked, and methods like `val` and `text` are not implemented on `DOMElement`. By wrapping a DOM element in a jQuery object you can get access to these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("a#edit").click(function() {
                $("div#search").addClass("hidden");
                $("div#edit").removeClass("hidden");
            alert($(this).text()); // $(this).text() should return the text contained within the relevant tag.
            return false;
            }); 
        } 
);
```