# how to - replace link text with image (using wp_nav_menu)

Tags: wordpress

first time I'm trying to do this so please bear with me :)

I'm building a WordPress theme, and while using wp_nav_menu I'm trying to replace a generated link text with a custom image I made.

So, in essence, what I need done:

```
    1) <a href="blah">this text needs to be replaced</a>
    2) <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/with-this-image.png" />
```

I've tried some different tests with jQuery, but I can't find the right combination to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace the text that is generated "this text needs to be replaced" with

```
 <img src="/images/with-this-image.png" />
```

if you want to do it with jquery drop an ID on the a tag and reference that ID.

Comment: alert($('#menu-item-83 a').html()); reveals the the anchor tag as well as the link text. The issue I'm having is that I don't know the proper jQuery code to replace the link text with the img stuff

Comment: You want to use $("#menu-item-83 a").text("<img src=''>")  [stackoverflow reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127669/finding-the-value-text-of-an-a-tag-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new menu so you don't overwrite your current one (makes it easier to switch back if you decide to change it.

In the new menu you've created, instead of adding pages or posts the traditional way (using the check-boxes and adding to menu), **you can use this method:**

Open a blank page (it won't be saved, it's just easier to get the html code for the next step). With the blank page open, click HTML to enter HTML view. Now upload the image you want to use for the navigation link. Copy the html code (make sure you don't copy the P Tags. The coppied result would look something like this:

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Home48x48.png" alt="Home" title="Home" width="48" />
```

**Now to add it to the new menu created:**
Go to the new menu you created and paste your image source from the last step into the custom menu label (if the menu items are already added it will say navigation label) where the field that has URL is where you'll add the actual link to your page.